# Google Sheets: Use ArrayFormula to copy a formula until a set value

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas

I'm trying to create a formula until a set value using ArrayFormula in Google Sheets.

The end result values can be viewed on the spreadsheet:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1yBC4oQuhKOkIkf3lQZGBKcZQ3YjU_5N6MCIJZzdt0O4/edit?usp=sharing

Thank you!

Comment: sheet is private

Comment: Sorry, corrected. 
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1yBC4oQuhKOkIkf3lQZGBKcZQ3YjU_5N6MCIJZzdt0O4/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

delete everything from red cells and use this in D4:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IFERROR(SUBSTITUTE(SPLIT(REPT("♠♥", B4:B-1)&
 REPT(B1/C4:C&"♥", C4:C), "♥"), "♠", )))
```

[image]